# Can you delete images created with createRemoteFileNode in Gatsbyjs source plugin?

Tags: gatsby

I'm creating a custom Gatsby source plugin using the cache to do incremental builds.  I have been through the [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/source-plugin-tutorial/) and it looks like nodes are being deleted and created/updated correctly during my builds.

However, when I look in the public/static folder of my project, processed images generated by `createRemoteFileNode` are still present after the parent node has been deleted.  I haven't been able to find a method to delete these files during build. Cleaning the cache would defeat the point of incremental builds.

Since these nodes are created in the `onCreateNode` method, it seems like `onDeleteNode` would be the appropriate place to handle this.  Alas, it seems that [method isn't available](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17457).

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node, 
  actions: { createNode },
  createNodeId,
  getCache,
}) => {
  if (
    node.media_image &&
    node.media_image.url
  ) {
    const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.media_image.url,
      parentNodeId: node.id,
      createNode,
      createNodeId,
      getCache,
    });
    if (fileNode) {
      node.remoteImage___NODE = fileNode.id;
    }
  }
//...
}
```

I suppose this isn't essential, but as the site grows, there could be many orphaned files sitting around and doing a lengthy rebuild of a large site wouldn't be fun. Any help appreciated!